# Convert Julian Date to Date in FM in iSeries DB2

Tags: date, frameworks, cognos, julian-date

How can I convert the Julian date of iSeries DB2 in FM ?

I have no issue with Julian date conversion with Netezza DB, but no luck for iSeries DB2 for AS400.

Comment: I see that DB2 supports as input to the DATE function both "Unformatted Julian" and "Julian" formats, which use year number and day-of-year number. It also has a JULIAN DATE function which will output a count of days since January 1, 4713 BC, Julian proleptic calendar. I think you should give an example of a date you want to convert from, in the form you have it, and exactly what you want to convert it to. Hopefully you have an example conversion you know is correct.

Comment: the julian date format i am getting from my source is 2015092 for 2015-04-01.. apart from that i am checking the _make_timestamp function of cognos fm..  what i found that if _make_timestamp (2015,1,33) yield 2015-02-02 : The extra day is carried to the consequence month... but _make_timestamp (2015,1,365) yield 2015-04-19 : I am expecting 2015-12-31. Any idea why it is so?.. 

perhaps i can apply _make_timestamp for this julian to date conversion..

Comment: Off the top of my head.  Something like 2015-01-01 + 91 days